# How do you create nested dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having difficulty to create nested dictionary from the below mentioned list:

```
student = ['Mike','Frank']
Type = ['Midterm1','Midterm2','Final']
Scores = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60]]
```

I am looking for following dictionary:

```
 Scorecard = {'Mike':'Midterm':10,'Midterm2':20,'Final':30},'Frank':   
             {'Midterm':40,'Midterm2':50,'Final':60}}
```

I was able to create student and type combination but having difficultly to nest the type and values at the student level.

The output would be

```
scorecard['Mike']['Midterm'] = 10
         ['Mike']['Midterm2'] = 20
```

Comment: `{stud: dict(zip(types, score)) for stud, score in zip(student, scores)}`

Comment: Thank you. I tested and it worked well

Answer (score 3):

Here's a succinct one-liner:

```
In [4]: dict(zip(student, (dict(zip(Type, score)) for score in Scores)))
Out[4]:
{'Frank': {'Final': 60, 'Midterm1': 40, 'Midterm2': 50},
 'Mike': {'Final': 30, 'Midterm1': 10, 'Midterm2': 20}}
```

Here it is with the looping a bit more explicit:

```
In [5]: scorecard = {}

In [6]: for st, score in zip(student, Scores):
   ...:     scorecard[st] = dict(zip(Type,score))
   ...:
   ...:

In [7]: scorecard
Out[7]:
{'Frank': {'Final': 60, 'Midterm1': 40, 'Midterm2': 50},
 'Mike': {'Final': 30, 'Midterm1': 10, 'Midterm2': 20}}
```